# Does affect not work with a clause?

Tags: word-usage

This is a problem I took from my exercise book:

> **Choose the correct word to complete the sentences. Sometimes both are correct.**
>
> Advertising is so powerful that it (causes/affects) people to buy
> things they don't want.

At first, I thought both were correct. Then I checked on the key answer and turned out my answer was incorrect (the answer is **causes**). I looked up the word in the dictionary and I noticed that there was no example that showed affect is followed by a clause rather than subject or predicate.

Does it mean, it is incorrect to use a clause after affect? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples from Google Books with a clause after *affect*:

> to indirectly *affect how* students think or feel about school

> But our genes ... *affect whether* we generally view the world positively or negatively.

> ...should not *affect whether* we can do surveillance...

> ...there are current policies that *affect whether* children will need care

Here's a possible use of affect similar to your example:

> Advertising is so powerful that it *affects how* people buy things.

> Advertising *affects* people so much that they buy things they don't need.

The example you gave needs a word that means *causes* directly. Here's another word that does that:

> Advertising *makes* people buy things.

Comment: Is affect analogous to influence? According to the dictionary. Influence can be also used to show the effect of something. From my understanding after reading your answer, could I confirm that cause is to make people (forcefully/they don't want it) and affect is to influence people (they do willingly)?

Comment: Yes, you could put *influence* in all the examples with *affect*. But, I don't think *cause* means that people don't want to do something. You can cause people to change their minds... make them change their minds... by influencing/affecting how they think.